# Unmet dependencies when doing apt-get install php-soap

Tags: apt, package-management, php, dependencies

I'm trying to install (as root) `php-soap` on Ubuntu 14.04.

I did `apt-get update` and `apt-get install php-soap`, and got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-115-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-115-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-115-generic but it is not going to be installed
 php-soap : Depends: php7.1-soap but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

My version of PHP is 5.6.xx so I don't want soap that depends on php7.1 as mentioned. I also don't known what the `linux-image-3.13.0-115-generic` has to do with soap. Is there a way of specifying the version of php-soap (i.e. for php 5.6), and how do I deal with the other issues?

Comment: first run `sudo apt-get -f install`, then try again see if it works.

Comment: Thanks - what does that do? (This is a live server)

Comment: tries to correct the unmet dependencies.

Comment: `apt-get -f install` fixes broken dependencies, as stated in `man apt-get`. Kudos for checking before running though..

Comment: Could you run `uname -r` and post the output?

Comment: uname -r results: 3.13.0-77-generic